# How to pass arguments to .exe file calling form php?

Tags: php

I am trying to call a `.exe` file in php with arguments 
    **I use this to run** `.exe`

```
$answer = shell_exec("calu.exe");
echo $answer."</br>";
```

This Shows result:
[image: Run from Php]
Now how to **pass argument** like entering **symbol** 
when i run this `.exe` file from **commad line** it ask Enter Symbol and the Enter two Number.
**Enter symbol**
[image: Run form command line]

**Enter Number**

[image: Enter numbers]

I want to do same from Php and print result .

 **How can i do so** ?

Comment: If "Dos Calculator" is a program of your own, you might want to modify it in order to accept "First number" and "Second number" as command line arguments. Then in php: `$answer = shell_exec("calu.exe" . $first_number . " " . $second_number);`

Comment: yes its my own .how can i set them as a command line arguments?

Comment: Depends, what language is it?

Comment: if in  Batch Script and if in python? @Lovy

Comment: Batch: You directly access the arguments as variables named `%1`, `%2`, etc...
Python: you need to `import sys`, and `sys.argv` will be a `list` of all your arguments.
Please note that either for batch and python, the arguments are retrieved as strings, and you need to convert them back to numbers.

Comment: is it possible to call a  function from .exe (python) in php?@Lovy

Comment: I don't think so, however you could add another optional command line argument. Then in python/batch, you would check if the argument has been passed, if so then you execute the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that *Dos Calculator* was a program of your own, written either in Python or in Batch.

What I would suggest then is to modify your program in order to handle command line arguments.

---

Some little snippets about how to handle command line arguments.
This will store your first argument, casted as a number, in `b`.

**In Batch:**

```
Set b=%1
```

**In Python:**

```
import sys
b = int(sys.argv[1]) # Index 0 is the name of your program
```

---

Then in php, you can call the your program with arguments like this:

```
$answer = shell_exec("calu.exe" . $first_number . " " . $second_number);
```